# Variable created and accessed in view not updated form controller : Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I earlier had in the code:

```
<a click="showText=true">

<div ng-show="showText"></div>
```

showText is not defined/declared in the controller scope.

I next had to add a $watch :

```
$scope.$watch("testCase",function(){
    $scope.showText = false;
});
```

However, this is not leading to the div getting hidden on the view. Also, i {{showText}} and yet the value is not updated to the view.

I later then created a toggle function :

```
<a click="toggle()">
```

toggle() negates the current value of showText. After doing this the $watch is able to update the value just fine.

Can anyone tell me the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/qjcqwhsw/

```
<div ng-app>
<a click="showText=true">
<div ng-show="showText"></div>
</div>
```

This works if you want to keep variable in controller then that time just initialize it to false
If you want to add watch then as you added you can add on 'showText'
Hope it will help you out

Answer (score 0):

From angular [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes):

> Scope inheritance is normally straightforward, and you often don't
>   even need to know it is happening... until you try 2-way data binding
>   (i.e., form elements, ng-model) to a primitive (e.g., number, string,
>   boolean) defined on the parent scope from inside the child scope. It
>   doesn't work the way most people expect it should work. What happens
>   is that the child scope gets its own property that hides/shadows the
>   parent property of the same name. This is not something AngularJS is
>   doing – this is how JavaScript prototypal inheritance works. New
>   AngularJS developers often do not realize that ng-repeat, ng-switch,
>   ng-view and ng-include all create new child scopes, so the problem
>   often shows up when these directives are involved.